# Genre of Dutch hip-hop diss track

Tags: genre, rap

Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MHjecHv3xPM

(Just listen to the melody, not to the song. It's in Dutch so I think a lot of you will not understand what they say.)

A similar version is good enough! It doesn't have to be 100% the same!

Comment: What do you mean for "similar version"...? Are you looking for a remix, a cover or something?

Comment: i mean the similar "beat". So if you have, as an example, "we will rock you", then a similar is also one that goes: boem boem clap, boem boem clap. But it doensn't have to be 100% the same

Answer (score 1):

This is early [Trap Music](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trap_music), also known as "Trap Rap" or "EDM Trap", which [grew out of the "Dirty South" rap sound](https://www.vibe.com/2017/04/important-trap-artists-feature/) in the early 2000s.  It has fast electronic drums over a slower synthesized melody line.  Here's a [early example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n48RyNTHyz0&list=PLgrlRVAQQVgUoAblaCphAQl06yU5ufvmr) by self-proclaimed Trap music creator TI.